# Post with HttpClient doesn't bind model

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Simple post from azure function to API

```
using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(installationServiceUrl, deviceInstallation.ToRequestBody()))
{...}
```

API receives the request, but cannot bind model from Request
[image: code]

But `Request.Content` is not null and contains sent `JSON` object. Content-Type header set to application/json.

Any suggestions?

Update: As I got it, some how API thinks that Model is simple string value (`locationId`), at least that is how I understand from from `ModelState.Keys` collection. It contains only `locationId`.

Update: `ToRequestBody` method just changes the shape of the object

```
    public static DeviceInstallationRequest ToRequestBody(this DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation)
    {
        return new DeviceInstallationRequest()
        {
                InstallationId = deviceInstallation.InstallationId,
                Name = deviceInstallation.Name,
                StartDateTime = deviceInstallation.StartDateTime,
                EndDateTime = deviceInstallation.EndDateTime,
                CreatedDateTime = deviceInstallation.CreatedDateTime,
                InstallationType = deviceInstallation.InstallationType,
                Production = deviceInstallation.Production,
                Default = deviceInstallation.Default
        }
    }
```

And expected model on API side:

```
public class BindDeviceInstallationRequest
{
        [Required]
        public string InstallationId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public InstallationType InstallationType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Production { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Default { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does `.ToRequestBody()` do?

Comment: .ToRequestBody() simply just changes the shape of the object making the projection and skipping some of the properties.

Comment: Ok noted. show the model being sent and the expected model on the action.

Comment: Suggestion just to troubleshoot. the same way you called `ReadAsStringAsync` within the action. Try `ReadAsAsync<T>` and see if the model is created.

Comment: @Nkosi Updated my question. Trying.

Comment: @Nkosi ReadAsAsync<> returns null :/

Comment: Then it means that the content being sent is not in a format that maps to the model. So when it tries to desrialize you will end up with null.

Comment: Need to review how you are posting the content from the client.

Comment: @Nkosi this is just simple call _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, object) nothing special...

Comment: Does it make any difference if you add `[FromUri]` to the `locationId` parameter?

Comment: @Crowcoder nope :/

Comment: Is there any way for you to check the text encoding used by client when sending request?

Comment: I am thinking, If you build the content yourself and send the request to see if the issue is with that extension method.

Comment: @Nkosi if I do it in that way JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindDeviceInstallationRequest>(await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()), it deserialize it correctly into the model class

Comment: hmm well that is odd. Then the issue is with how the model binder is parsing the request content. Still sounds like the double serialization issue. Try the suggestion in my answer and see if the model binds

Comment: check to make sure your referenced packages are up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is an encoding issue try building the content yourself and sending it to the server,

```
DeviceInstallationRequest model = deviceInstallation.ToRequestBody();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(installationServiceUrl, content)) {
    //...
}
```

that way you have complete control of what is being sent to the server.

While debugging, inspect the raw JSON from the client and what is received on the server.